# autocomplete is not a function error

Tags: php, jquery, search, autocomplete

I'm working in twitter Bootstrap with PHP. I make a search form and apply autocomplete to search field but its not working, though its working fine when I test it outside the my working directory.

Here are my **jquery** files:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#term").autocomplete({
                        source:'action.php',
                        minLength:1
                    });
                });
        </script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
        </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
        </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#datepicker3").datepicker();
        </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#datepicker4").datepicker();
        </script>
```

and here is my **search field** in the form:

```
<input type="text" class="span3 search-query" id="term" name="term" placeholder="search by customer-name, company-name and location" autocomplete="off">
```

Here is the **css** for autocomplete:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Here is my **action.php** file:

```
<?php
include("config.php"); 
$term=$_GET["term"];

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers where name like '%".$term."%'");
$json=array();

    while($customer=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(

                    'value'=> $customer["name"],
                    'label'=>$customer["name"],

                        );
    }

 echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: Use full paths for your autocomplete.js include.

Comment: update your `jquery.js` file and try again.

Comment: check for wrong path in network tab. You should have to use absolute path or set base tag of html document

Answer (score 0):

On Google chrome press F12 before loading the page and see in the 'Network' tab if the jquery.autocomplete.js is loading. If its not, Please use the correct relative path for it.

Comment: Try to see the browser console if it has details of the error you are getting.